# How to get a “not-allowed” cursor on a disabled link

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to get a `not-allowed` cursor on my disabled link. I've tried to add it to the disabled event but it wouldn't work there, then I tried to introduce a hover effect with the same cursor event. Any ideas on how to get that to work? I've included my code CSS here:

```
.disabled {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: not-allowed;
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.disabled:hover {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

and my HTML here:

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="disabled">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to remove `pointer-events: none;` to make this work.

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}

.disabled {
  /* pointer-events: none; */ /* removed */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.disabled:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html" class="disabled">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: for reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: So is there any way to turn off the hover effect and get the not-allowed cursor? that was kind of my goal

Comment: This does not solve the problem because the page switching link remains active.

Answer (score 2):

Once pointer-events: none; is removed, the cursor: not-allowed should work already.

```css
.disabled {
cursor: not-allowed;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.disabled:hover {
    cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="index.html" class="disabled">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the "pointer-events: none;"

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `pointer-events: none`, that prevents `cursor: not-allowed` from showing correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to set pointer-events: visible,  to show cursor: not-allowed on the disabled button